# How to completely uninstall gnome-shell and all extensions?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm having a bit of trouble getting gnome-shell to work ever since I installed an extension (I don't know which) on 11.10. So what I would like to know is: How can I completely uninstall EVERYTHING gnome-shell related (all the extensions, gnome-tweak-tool, etc.), everything - so I can start fresh and re-install 'em all one by one?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After a long and hard search (for me anyway) I found it:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extensions-*
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This command will perform the uninstallation:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache depends gnome-core|cut -f 2 -d :|xargs`
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will remove the gnome-shell package and any other dependent packages which are no longer needed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-shell
```

This command will remove just the gnome-shell package:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```