# Black screen after uninstalling "gnome-tweaks"

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 21.04

After executing the following command from this question, my 21.04 Ubuntu installation ended up on a black screen. (My goal was to get rid of gnome extensions since I was no longer using it).

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-shell
```

I have already tried to use boot-repair, but to no avail. Nothing happens and the black screen is still there (though I can access GRUB). Does anyone know how I could fix this?

[How to completely uninstall gnome-shell and all extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103520/how-to-completely-uninstall-gnome-shell-and-all-extensions)

Edit: I think I may have just uninstalled what wasn't supposed to be gnome-tweaks, great.

Comment: *"I think I may have just uninstalled what wasn't supposed to be gnome-tweaks":* Yes. That's GNOME Shell being used by default since Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: and it wasn't even a command listed in the reference you gave. Are you at a point where you can reinstall 21.04 from scratch?

Comment: At grub, press `e`, then go to the line with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-..` and at the end add `init=/bin/bash`. Ctl+x and exit. Then, when you are in terminal as root, you can install `gnome-shell` again and hopefully this solve the problem.

Comment: @Karlom's solution did the trick. Everything is working perfectly, again. I was very clumsy by not paying attention what was written past gnome, my bad. Thanks to all for the assistance nonetheless.

Comment: Glad that  could help. Yes, this trick works in many occasions, I frequently use it for example when I need to change root password remotely. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At grub, press `e`, then in the page that opens go to the line with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-...` and at the end of it add `init=/bin/bash`.

`Ctl+x` to save the grub parameters and exit.

This gives you root terminal access, where you can install gnome-shell again and hopefully this solve the problem.